Lenovo Ideapad Slim3 – internal keyboard stops working after prolonged suspend
I'm experiencing an issue with my Lenovo Ideapad Slim3 with a AMD CPU and graphics running the latest version of Ubuntu. When I close the laptop lid and it remains in suspend mode for an extended period, the internal laptop keyboard stops working upon waking up. The touchpad and any externally connected keyboards continue to function normally.

I'm having this two. I read elsewhere, then confirmed, that the system doesn't actually sleep. It wakes up right after going into sleep. According to a report I read it is because of the touchscreen. But the system devices layout is different in Ubuntu from what's described in that report, so I couldn't follow the advice there. I'm not even sure my device has touchscreen!
